# Reusing HttpClient for multipart download

Tags: c#, task, httpclient, download-manager

I'm reusing `HttpClient` for all my download task because I always saw in SO that I should reuse httpclient for everything. But I'm getting this exception `Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: The request was canceled.`

**This is the things I've done so far.**

1. Make new instance of HttpClient for every download task (worked, but not reusing the httpclient)
2. Reduce the number of task to 2 (works, anything above 2 throws an exception)
3. Remove `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` from request message (works, but it takes too long to start the download, I think it continue to read all files before starting the stream) 
4. Make `HttpClient` timeout to infinite (didn't work)
5. Make used of `HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync` method and set read timeout to infinite (didn't work)

**Here is the code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => new Downloader().Download(
                "https://ia800703.us.archive.org/34/items/1mbFile/1mb.mp4",
                "1mb.mp4"
            )).Wait();
        }
    }

    public class Downloader
    {
        HttpClient httpClient;

        public Downloader()
        {
            httpClient = new HttpClient();
        }

        public async Task Download(string url, string saveAs)
        {
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Head, url), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            var parallelDownloadSuported = response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Contains("bytes");
            var contentLength = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength ?? 0;

            if (parallelDownloadSuported)
            {
                const double numberOfParts = 5.0;
                var tasks = new List<Task>();
                var partSize = (long)Math.Ceiling(contentLength / numberOfParts);

                File.Create(saveAs).Dispose();

                for (var i = 0; i < numberOfParts; i++)
                {
                    var start = i * partSize + Math.Min(1, i);
                    var end = Math.Min((i + 1) * partSize, contentLength);

                    tasks.Add(
                        Task.Run(() => DownloadPart(url, saveAs, start, end))
                        );
                }

                await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
            }
        }

        private async void DownloadPart(string url, string saveAs, long start, long end)
        {
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(saveAs, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, 1024, true))
            {
                var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
                message.Headers.Add("Range", string.Format("bytes={0}-{1}", start, end));

                fileStream.Position = start;
                await httpClient.SendAsync(message, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result.Content.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

codes are from :[here](https://gist.github.com/subena22jf/3358b8609966203502a5)